# Can I use these wordpress tags to format source code for a wordpress installed in hostgator?

Tags: wordpress, hosting

1. I am starting a new blog and thinking to go with hostgator.
2. Next plan is to install wordpress on it.
3. The blog will have code being displayed on it and the code should be displayed with good formatting and color highlighting. I saw this, https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/ and am wondering if I can use it on the wordpress installed on hostgator.
4. I did also see this link - http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts, but I am more inclined to use the tags specified in point 3's link.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this on any hosting service. You will just put that in your blog post, not anything that would be up to the hosting service.

Comment: okay, will i be able to do it in the wordpress installed in hostgator.com ? My worry is i will have to go ONLY thru wordpress.com to get those tags.

Comment: I think that you can just put that inside your wordpress blogpost when you post it when you are signed in on your website.